# kernlab regression

Tags: r, regression, kernlab

Anyone encountered this difficulty with `kernlab` regression?  It seems like it's losing some scaling factors or something, but perhaps I'm calling it wrong.

```
library(kernlab)
df <- data.frame(x=seq(0,10,length.out=1000))
df$y <- 3*df$x + runif(1000) - 3
plot(df)
res <- ksvm(y ~ x, data=df, kernel='vanilladot')
lines(df$x, predict(res), col='blue', lwd=2)
```

[image: svm-results]

With this toy example I can get reasonable results if I explicitly pass `newdata=df`, but with my real data I've found no such workaround.  Any insight?

Answer (score 1):

Passing a `newdata` argument is the correct way to do it (or else it will use the internally-scaled data, like you saw). The typical way is something like:

```
newx = seq(min(df$x), max(df$x), len=100)
lines(newx, predict(res, newdata=data.frame(x=newx)), col='blue', lwd=2)
```

If this still doesn't work on your real data, please elaborate...

For what it's worth, I usually prefer to manually scale my data first, and then set `scaled=F`. That way you don't have to worry about this type of thing that can crop up at different times.

**EDIT**: I should also add that when you make the `newdata` data frame, the variable names should match what you used to create the model, and not necessarily be "x".

Comment: That seems like a bug, right?  Scaling shouldn't depend on whether `newdata` is implicit or explicit.

Comment: In my real task, I'm doing cross-validation, so I pass `newdata=` to get the `predict()` result.

Comment: Not sure. Definitely possible, but I imagine someone could also argue good reasons for plotting what is actually in the model by default.

Comment: Just confirmed in private email with Alexandros that it's a bug, which they'll fix in the next release.  Thanks for the help.